# Finding mean, standard deviation, and standard error of the levels of a variable across multiple subjects in R

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to find mean, sd, and se for nine different conditions across 32 subjects so that I can create a plot. Every subject has a frequency value associated with each level of condition.

This is how my data looks like

```
dput(condition_count)
structure(list(subj_no = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32"), class = "factor"), 
    condition = c("A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", 
    "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", 
    "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", 
    "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", 
    "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", 
    "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", 
    "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - gain", "A - loss", "A - loss", 
    "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", 
    "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", 
    "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", 
    "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", 
    "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", 
    "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", "A - loss", 
    "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", 
    "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", 
    "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", 
    "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", 
    "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", 
    "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - gain", 
    "B - gain", "B - gain", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", 
    "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", 
    "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", 
    "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", 
    "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", 
    "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", 
    "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "B - loss", "C - gain", 
    "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", 
    "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", 
    "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", 
    "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", 
    "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", 
    "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", "C - gain", 
    "C - gain", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", 
    "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", 
    "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", 
    "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", 
    "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", 
    "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", "C - loss", 
    "C - loss", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", "C - neutral", 
    "C - neutral", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", 
    "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", 
    "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", 
    "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", 
    "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", 
    "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", 
    "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - gain", "D - loss", "D - loss", 
    "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", 
    "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", 
    "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", 
    "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", 
    "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", 
    "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss", "D - loss"
    ), frequency = c(13L, 13L, 18L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 
    10L, 13L, 23L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    12L, 7L, 15L, 8L, 9L, 18L, 13L, 11L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
    14L, 18L, 17L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 15L, 21L, 13L, 
    10L, 10L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 7L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 
    18L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 21L, 38L, 18L, 34L, 27L, 39L, 
    31L, 14L, 8L, 31L, 23L, 22L, 34L, 15L, 37L, 26L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 18L, 20L, 26L, 18L, 43L, 31L, 24L, 28L, 25L, 22L, 28L, 
    26L, 36L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 7L, 15L, 10L, 14L, 12L, 
    16L, 15L, 12L, 10L, 13L, 19L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 18L, 
    24L, 15L, 25L, 6L, 18L, 18L, 5L, 13L, 19L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 
    8L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 
    5L, 6L, 5L, 24L, 12L, 21L, 16L, 26L, 22L, 20L, 41L, 45L, 
    20L, 25L, 14L, 14L, 28L, 21L, 20L, 49L, 49L, 33L, 27L, 18L, 
    22L, 24L, 11L, 18L, 23L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 18L, 23L, 16L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L)), row.names = c(NA, 286L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using

```
ddply(condition_count, .(subj_no, condition), function(x){
  c(mean=mean(x$frequency), sd = sd(x$frequency), 
    se = sd(x$frequency)/sqrt(length(x$frequency)))
```

but it's not yielding mean, sd, or se for each condition.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
condition.count %>% group_by(condition) %>% 
  summarise(mean= mean(frequency), sd=sd(frequency), 
            se = sd(frequency) / sqrt(length(frequency)))
```

| condition | mean | sd | se |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 A - gain | 11.6 | 3.71 | 0.656 |
| 2 A - loss | 12.0 | 3.53 | 0.625 |
| 3 B - gain | 25.3 | 8.44 | 1.49 |
| 4 B - loss | 3 | 0.842 | 0.149 |
| 5 C - gain | 13.7 | 4.55 | 0.804 |
| 6 C - loss | 2.07 | 0.828 | 0.151 |
| 7 C - neutral | 6.31 | 1.49 | 0.263 |
| 8 D - gain | 23.9 | 9.74 | 1.72 |
| 9 D - loss | 2.22 | 1.13 | 0.199 |

Comment: The output I get is just one row of mean, sd, and se

Comment: Works for me. What `unique(condition.count$condition)` gives you?

Comment: It gives me NULL

Comment: I updated r to the latest version and it worked. Thanks!